# My Erlang project has multiple applications: How should I start them?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I'm struggling, as an OTP noobie, to understand how to structure my Erlang project. So far it has several applications under an app directory managed by rebar:

```
proj_root
   apps
      app1
      app2
      appN
   rebar.config
```

I can start app1, say, in the shell with application:start(app1). No doubt I could repeat this through appN. But is there a preferred or better way? Can I, say, write a function that bundles all these starts? If so, where do I put it?

I have several other questions along this line, but will post separately.

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed start applications manually as you suggest. This can quickly become burdensome if you have many applications and there are dependencies between them.

**Automating the process is quite easy** to implement with a recursive function. If you try to start an application while one or more dependencies is not running, `application:start/1` will fail and return `{error, {not_started, App}}`. This function can be in any of your applications or even in its own.

However, this manual (or automated) way to proceed is **not the OTP way**, even if it can prove useful (typically for tests…). If you follow OTP principles, **you are supposed to create a release** with a `.rel` file containing all your applications. OTP releases are composed of a set of applications (yours and system applications they depend on), an emulator and a **boot script** that will start all applications (and handle dependencies). Starting a node with your applications can be performed by using the `-boot` flag to [`erl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) pointing to the proper boot script.

This is quite complex and rebar can actually [build releases](https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Release-handling). It will even produce shell scripts to start nodes with all your applications using the OTP boot mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. This is exactly the kind of guidance I've been looking for. I've looked at creating a release, but the density of docs scared me off. But you've given me motivation to dig in and learn what I've got to learn.

Comment: I found rebar to be very helpful when it comes to building releases. Specifically: 

`rebar create-node
rebar generate`

Of course, you should read the documentation and understand the process behind the automation eventually but rebar tends to get you going more quickly while adhering to OTP standards.